# how to send Text Messege/ Alert to non app user?

Tags: swift

Is there an API I can use or some way that i can send the user location as an alert/text to someone who doesn't have the app but is designated as a "special contact" in the app? Thank you!

Comment: You could use Twilio to send an SMS.

Comment: @TylerLiu https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/sending-text-messages-in-swift-with-twilio.html this was the only article I found on it, have you ever used twilio?

Comment: Yes I have, although not with Swift.